# How to add an element (not a tab) to the tab bar?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a react app that uses ant d. I have added an ant d tab bar and made it sticky.
I now want to add a button to the very right of the ant-d tab bar. Something like this?

```
<Tabs className={sticky}>
  <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
    Content of Tab Pane 1
  </TabPane>
  <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
    Content of Tab Pane 2
  </TabPane>
  <button>Click me</button>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabs](https://ant.design/components/tabs/) take a `prop` called [tabBarExtraContent](https://ant.design/components/tabs/#API) which takes a react node.

Here [is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tab-add-button-h5jol?file=/src/App.js) I created for you.

**Code snippet:**

```js
<Tabs tabBarExtraContent={<button>Click me</button>} className={"sticky"}>
        <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
          Content of Tab Pane 1
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
          Content of Tab Pane 2
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
```